# Почему в Android 6.0 не работает GPS?

Tags: android, gps

Почему в Android 6.0 не работает GPS?

```
locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    locationManager.requestSingleUpdate(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, this, null);
```

---

```
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            locationManager.requestSingleUpdate(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, this, null);
            return;
        }
    }



 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

Comment: Дошлооо, добавьте `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Начиная с `Android 6.0` и выше нужно обрабатывать такие `permission`.
Новые правила от `Google`. Пользователь сам должен дать разрешение на такие данные как определение местоположение, а не просто где-то прочитать, что используются такие данные.

В вашем случае нужно сделать так:

```
locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    locationManager.requestSingleUpdate(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, this, null);
    return;
}
```

Добавьте `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />`

т.к. `if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,` **Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)** `!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)`

Comment: А зачем? если в предыдущих версиях и так нормально было. ЗАчем этот бред?

Comment: @xTIGRx Новые правила от Google. Пользователь сам должен дать разрешение на такие данные как определение местоположение, а не просто где-то прочитать, что используются такие данные. Я думаю это норм хоть и добавляет гемора нам разрабам.

Comment: @xTIGRx потому что теперь пользователь может запрещать и разрешать использование GPS уже после установки, наплевав на то, что приложение просило изначально.

Comment: "спрашивая у пользователя давать добро на использование или нет." - что вы говорите?

Comment: @s_klepcha исправил

Comment: Странно но запроса никакого нет

Comment: @xTIGRx в телефоне зайдите на свойства приложения -> разрешения и уберите тумблер на определения местоположения. И заново запустите приложения. Запрос должен появиться.

Comment: А этот код который выше. Он будет работать для Android 4 или 5?

Comment: @xTIGRx инфа 100, сам такое использую с 4.0.3 проблем не было

Comment: @iFr0z, А какой провайдер лучше использовать? GPS? или Network?

Comment: @iFr0z, Просто из за вашего кода  уменя ошибка такая появляется и крашится все.

`Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: "gps" location provider requires ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission.`

Comment: @xTIGRx значит где-то раньше используется строка `locationManager.requestSingleUpdate(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, this, null);`, которая не обработана или что-то другое, нужен код на который он ругается. В любом случае нужно обрабатывать так как я написал и собственно написал гугл.

Comment: @iFr0z, Добавил код выше в вопрос.

Comment: @xTIGRx вообще лучше Network. Но по уму лучше все ситуации прописать, т.е. сначала вместе и gps и network, а потом по отдельности на случай если GPS или Network отпали каким-то макаром

Comment: @xTIGRx он ругается на этот кусок кода? а где все остальное?оО Вы в `splash` прям обработали это? Может есть еще где-то код с этим делом всем?

Comment: @iFr0z,
1) Вы тестили свой код на устройстве Android 6.0 или 7.0?
2) Нет в других классах нет. К тому же приложение вылетает на том коде который вы дали мне

Comment: @xTIGRx 1) он у меня в релизе даже, конечно тестил. 2) попробуйте не `requestSingleUpdate`, а `requestLocationUpdates` 3) вставьте полный код ошибки пожалуйста

Comment: @xTIGRx теперь работает?