# Не работает Gps на Api 23 и выше

Tags: java, android

Ребят всем привет знаю что Google добавил для прошивки 6.0 и вше условпроверки ,все сделал добавил,работает на вем кроме апи выше 23 ...Почему ???вот куски кода и 
вот мой манифест

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />


protected static final int REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS = 0x1;
    private FusedLocationProviderApi locationProvider = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi;
    private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
    private LocationRequest locationRequest;

 locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        locationRequest.setInterval(1000);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
```

и вот

```
 @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        requestLocationUpdates();
    }

    private void requestLocationUpdates() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Connect on",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, locationRequest, this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }
    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.d(LOGSERVICE,"latitud" + location.getLatitude());
        Log.d(LOGSERVICE,"lotitude" + location.getLongitude());
        myLatitude = location.getLatitude();
        myLongitude = location.getLongitude();
        lat.setText(String.valueOf(myLatitude));
        lot.setText(String.valueOf(myLongitude));


    }
    public void settingsrequest() {
        LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        locationRequest.setInterval(1 * 1000);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(1 * 1000);
        LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
                .addLocationRequest(locationRequest);
        builder.setAlwaysShow(true); //this is the key ingredient

        PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result =
                LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(googleApiClient, builder.build());
        result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult result) {
                final Status status = result.getStatus();
                final LocationSettingsStates state = result.getLocationSettingsStates();
                switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                        // All location settings are satisfied. The client can initialize location
                        // requests here.
                        break;
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                        // Location settings are not satisfied. But could be fixed by showing the user
                        // a dialog.
                        try {
                            // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                            // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                            status.startResolutionForResult(MainActivity.this, REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
                        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                            // Ignore the error.
                        }
                        break;
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                        // Location settings are not satisfied. However, we have no way to fix the
                        // settings so we won't show the dialog.
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
// Check for the integer request code originally supplied to startResolutionForResult().
            case REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS:
                switch (resultCode) {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        requestLocationUpdates();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Gps turn on",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;
                    case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                        settingsrequest();//keep asking if imp or do whatever
                        break;
                }
                break;
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        settingsrequest();
        googleApiClient.connect();
        Log.d(LOGSERVICE,"onSTart" );
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (googleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            requestLocationUpdates();
        }
        Log.d(LOGSERVICE,"onResume" );
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, this);
        Log.d(LOGSERVICE,"onPause" );
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        googleApiClient.disconnect();
        Log.d(LOGSERVICE,"onStop" );
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d(LOGSERVICE,"onDestroy" );
    }
}
```

Comment: А вы запрашиваете пермишены? Проверка ответа есть, а запроса я не вижу. Надо где-то вызывать `requestPermissions` и, возможно, не инициализировать код работы с gps до получения пермишена. И еще у вас todo в `requestLocationUpdates` на это намекает.

Comment: Ок как быть ? как запросить ?не могли бы вдать ответ

Comment: Для полного ответа надо добавить изрядное количество модификаций в ваш код, а я с мобильника). Общую суть я описал, запрос пермишенов выглядит примерно так: `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);`

Comment: И куда добавить Это доброо ?

Comment: Для начала в `requestLocationUpdates`, там где у вас комментарии и todo

Comment: Да я понел ,но также я прочел про разрешения типо нельзя 2 разрешения стаить.Мне удалить разрешение манифесте ?

Comment: Нет. В манифесте оно нужно. Если не нужно 2 разрешения, то удалите или разрешение на точные координаты или на примерные. И из манифеста и из кода. Но мне кажется это не обязательно. Еще есть соседний тред http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/557137/Почему-в-android-6-0-не-работает-gps

Comment: @Спасибо товарищ за помощь все получилось .Я не знаю но щас же используют слово товарищ у Русских для уважительного обращения Да?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53028/discussion-between-elik-and-lllyct).

Comment: Слушай он находит координат один раз но не изменяет его

Comment: почему так ???????